# How can I create my own VolleyError object in android

Tags: android, android-volley

I mostly use `Volley` to do network calls in my android apps. `Volley` always has two callbacks:

**1) onSuccess(String response)**

**2) onError(VolleyError error)**

Now I am more interested in this VolleyError object. This `object` can be instance of `NetworkError`, `AuthFailureError`, `TimeoutError` etc.

**I want to create my own `VolleyError` object of type `AuthFailureError`.** So that I can pass that object to a callback method.

Here is my method:

```
if ((currentTime - refreshTime) < (expiresInFromPrefs - 5)) {
                //token is live
                tokenCallback.success(accessTokenFromPrefs);
            }else{
                //token expired
                Log.e(TAG,"token expired");
                tokenCallback.failure(VolleyError myObject);
            }
```

This is how VolleyError class looks like:

```
public class VolleyError extends Exception {
    public final NetworkResponse networkResponse;
    private long networkTimeMs;

    public VolleyError() {
        networkResponse = null;
    }

    public VolleyError(NetworkResponse response) {
        networkResponse = response;
    }

    public VolleyError(String exceptionMessage) {
       super(exceptionMessage);
       networkResponse = null;
    }

    public VolleyError(String exceptionMessage, Throwable reason) {
        super(exceptionMessage, reason);
        networkResponse = null;
    }

    public VolleyError(Throwable cause) {
        super(cause);
        networkResponse = null;
    }

    /* package */ void setNetworkTimeMs(long networkTimeMs) {
       this.networkTimeMs = networkTimeMs;
    }

    public long getNetworkTimeMs() {
       return networkTimeMs;
    }
}
```

This is how `AuthFailureError` looks like:

```
public class AuthFailureError extends VolleyError {
    /** An intent that can be used to resolve this exception. (Brings up the password dialog.) */
    private Intent mResolutionIntent;

    public AuthFailureError() { }

    public AuthFailureError(Intent intent) {
        mResolutionIntent = intent;
    }

    public AuthFailureError(NetworkResponse response) {
        super(response);
    }

    public AuthFailureError(String message) {
        super(message);
    }

    public AuthFailureError(String message, Exception reason) {
        super(message, reason);
    }

    public Intent getResolutionIntent() {
        return mResolutionIntent;
    }

    @Override
    public String getMessage() {
        if (mResolutionIntent != null) {
            return "User needs to (re)enter credentials.";
        }
        return super.getMessage();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> I want to create my own VolleyError object of type AuthFailureError

Then, you need to extends `AuthFailureError` instead of `Exception`.

```
public class VolleyError extends AuthFailureError
```

Because, extending `Exception` class makes `VolleyError` class type of `Exception` not `AuthFailureError` class.

Comment: @XoXo Could you be specific, what is your question now ??

Comment: The class I showed is party of Volley library. I want to pass a `Throwable` or `VolleyError` object with `AuthFailureError` to the callback. I am not making any `Volley` call. So automatically `Volley` wont give me the VolleyError object in `onError` response.

Comment: @XoXo you are question is not clear because you are not clear what has to be done. You are creating so much confusion on what are you trying to achieve

Comment: @XoXo  `Throwable` is super class of all exception, making any exception of type `VolleyError` implicity become type of `Throwable`. Then, I'm not sure what are you asking

Comment: `tokenCallBack.failure()` method expects a `Throwable` object. As I tried passing a `Throwable` object it didn't workout because it was expecting `Id`. That is available in `VolleyError` object by default. I just want to create my own Throwable object which consist `401 status code` as `networkResponse`.

Comment: @XoXo What do you mean by didn't worked?? and what Id ? I already mentioned in your earlier post. Be specific with your question and code. You are posting irrelevant things in your question. Just point out the part of the code and show your exception and tell what are your trying to achieve. which is make little clear.

Comment: i want to create a Throwable object without making network call. The Network error should be AuthFailureError. i.e 401 error or else token expiry error

Comment: @XoXo I don't know what is network call and all these. If you are asking anything specific to Java then I can answer

Comment: As you must have seen in my question. I am trying to pass a Throwable object to the failure() method. It's just simple if else statement there. No network calls. If the token is expired pass a Throwable object or else pass the access token

Comment: @XoXo I'm asking very simple thing. **Could you point out your code where you are having trouble ??** Remove everything else.

Answer (score 0):

I assume, you implemented a [custom Volley request](https://developer.android.com/training/volley/request-custom.html). You don't need to extend the `VolleyError` class, just use one of the constructors, e.g.

```
public VolleyError(Throwable cause)
```

to pass your custom error (must be a `Throwable`) from your custom request.

Comment: i want to create a Throwable object without making network call. The Network error should be AuthFailureError. i.e 401 error or else token expiry error

Comment: Just an Idea: extend the `RequestQueue` and override the `add` method.

Comment: Can you elaborate a little please.

Comment: As you must have seen in my question. I am trying to pass a Throwable object to the failure() method. It's just simple if else statement there. No network calls. If the token is expired pass a Throwable object or else pass the access token.

Comment: Please make clear in which class and method you call your `tokenCallback.failure`.